# cargar contenido html en view Source angular

Tags: angular

Buenas soy un poco nuevo en angular y me gustaría saber como hacer para que muestre el contenido html en viewSource de la página, para algunas de las secciones mas estáticas y de cara a SEO, como el como funciona etc etc.

He visto varias paginas en angular que lo estan haciendo por ejemplo en esta: [como funciona](https://carnovo.com/es/comparador-coche-nuevo)

Aquí podemos ver como muestran el código "abierto" de  `<cnv-root>` en la home y todo lo que serian paginas "corporativas" también, pero si ya vas al login o las funcionalidades dentro de la aplicación como el [login](https://carnovo.com/es/client/login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que los robots indexadores puedan recoger la información de una SPA (Single page application) es necesario utilizar server side rendering.

En angular esta tecnología se llama **Universal** y la puedes encontrar documentada aquí: https://angular.io/guide/universal

PD: Esto no aplica a AngularJS, solo a Angular 2+ aunque también se puede solucionar este caso en AngularJS con el uso de Prerender.io:
https://prerender.io/

En ambos casos lo que se pretende es servir la página ya renderizada desde el servidor, con los elementos que normalmente son renderizados en el cliente.